# Tag needs to be closed in same line in Jasmine beforeEach function?

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing jasmine tests for my javascript that requires a select tag with two or three options before each test. So, I placed this code in my beforeEach function

```
$('<select class="tags" multiple name="tagList" id="tagListID" title="Tag List" size=3 class="form-control select"><option onmousedown="multiSelect(event, this)" value="java" id="java">'+ tag1 +'</option><option onmousedown="multiSelect(event, this)" value="php" id="php">'+ tag2 +'</option> </select>').appendTo('body');
```

which works. But, when I broke the single line into multiple lines using appendTo('body') function my tests didn't pass.

```
$('<select class="tags" multiple name="tagList" id="tagListID" title="TagList">').appendTo('body');
$('<option onmousedown="multiSelect(event, this)" value="java" id="java">'+ tag1 +'</option>').appendTo('body');
$('<option onmousedown="multiSelect(event, this)" value="php" id="php">'+ tag2 +'</option>').appendTo('body');
$('</select>').appendTo('body');
```

I don't know how to make this single line into multiple lines. Is it not working because the opening and the closing tag should be on the same line(I don't think so).

Thanks

Comment: jQuery objects can only wrap complete DOM elements, not HTML fragments.  `$('</select>')` makes no sense.

Comment: @SLaks Wait you are right, so the $ in the beginning doesn't really append to the body or does it with jQuery, never used that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't this also work since its still considering the next line as the same script? In Javascript (Vanilla) I simply use the + whenever I need to start on a new line and reintroduce the quotes. I seen people also use (`) to open and (`) to close at the end which does the same functionality but without the (+)'s.

```
$('<select class="tags" multiple name="tagList" id="tagListID" title="TagList">' +
'<option onmousedown="multiSelect(event, this)" value="java" id="java">'+ tag1 +'</option>' +
'<option onmousedown="multiSelect(event, this)" value="php" id="php">'+ tag2 +'</option>' +
'</select>').appendTo('body');
```

Comment: You absolutely made my day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did this work as intended for you? The $ is not suppose to be there, I will edit my answer.